# Swift support library included twice in .ipa

Tags: swift, fastlane

I try to create .ipa for release using fastlane 2.19.1. There was duplicate swift support library. Which one is required?

```
./Payload/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
./Payload/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
./Payload/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
./Payload/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
./Payload/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
./Payload/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
./Payload/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
./Payload/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
./Payload/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftSecurity.dylib
./Payload/Client.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
./SwiftSupport/libswiftCore.dylib
./SwiftSupport/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
./SwiftSupport/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
./SwiftSupport/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
./SwiftSupport/libswiftDarwin.dylib
./SwiftSupport/libswiftDispatch.dylib
./SwiftSupport/libswiftFoundation.dylib
./SwiftSupport/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
./SwiftSupport/libswiftSecurity.dylib
./SwiftSupport/libswiftUIKit.dylib
```